# How To DataBind Button per row in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi I was wondering how would I be able to get the particular cell value in my gridview (assuming that it only returns 1 row) so I would be able to overwrite other data in the db that is associated to that cell value. I'm thinking of data binding button per row, but how would I be able to do that?

here is my markup for gridview:

```
<asp:GridView id="gvInfo" runat="server" OnRowCommand="Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);" AutoGenerateColumns="true" EmptyDataText="Sorry, No Results Found. Enter User again." Visible="true">
                <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Button id="btnUpdate" Text="Update" runat="server" OnClick="update" Visible="false"/>
                  <asp:Button id="btnUpdatePin" Text="Update Pin" runat="server" OnClick="updatePin" Visible="false" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
         </Columns>
         </asp:GridView>
```

I have tried this to get it but nothing happened:

```
protected void update(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int status;
    string idc = gvInfo.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
    if (chkIsAuthorized.Checked == true) 
    {
        status = 1;
    } 
    else 
    {
        status = 0;
    }
    string sql="UPDATE starlode_users SET isauthorized = @isauthorized WHERE idcnumber=@idcnumber;";
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings ["DBCON"].ConnectionString;
    using (NpgsqlConnection dbcon = new NpgsqlConnection(cs)) 
    {
        dbcon.Open();
        using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, dbcon)) 
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isauthoried", status);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idcnumber", idc);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

}
```

Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' to your button and in your code behind you can get the row that raised the event.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="UpdateData"  CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'/>
```

In your codebehind subscribe to gridview's row command event.

```
protected void gvInfo_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "UpdateData")
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow row = gvInfo.Rows[index];

                   string cellText = row.Cells[0].Text;

            }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me what the "UpdateData" role is ? or What it is suppose to be ?

Comment: UpdateData is the command name specified with your control within gridview. It can be anything you like. for example you can specify CommandName="XYZ" for your button and then when gridview's row command event gets fired you can check if  command name is "XYZ" and take action accordingly. To know which row fired event you need to pass that value as a command argument. In above code all command argument is doing is passing the index of the row from where button is clicked. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907626.aspx

Comment: Should I also put RowCommand="gvInfo_RowCommand" ?

Comment: @Redel Ramos Yes you need to subscribe to Gridview's rowcommand event. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx

Comment: And say I'm going to get it upon button click then should I call this method inside button clicke event in code behind ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get `GridViewRow` of `SelectedRow` upon Button click by type casting the `sender` parameter to get the reference of the `GridViewRow`

```
 protected void update(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Button btn = sender as Button;
         GridViewRow gr = (btn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow);
         string idc = gr.Cells[0].Text;
    }
```